# Why i'm getting 403 on Spring boot security basic authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I have followed the tutorial http://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-security-rest-jpa-hibernate-mysql-crud-example

Note: *`Working on Spring-boot, Spring Data JPA, Security and basic authentication`*

My code is below

**UserDetailsService.java**

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("UserName: " + userName);
    User activeUserInfo = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);

    System.out.println("Role D : " + activeUserInfo.getUserRole().getName()); //This prints 'ADMIN' as expected
    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getUserRole().getName());
    System.out.println("User : " + activeUserInfo.getUserName()); //This prints my username 'test123' as expected
    System.out.println("PWD : " + activeUserInfo.getPassword()); //This prints '$2a$10$PN/MwjCHtCWsI4auW6Q8AOxb4dug4WSO8tfINySqHZ8eYVjFKIAW6' as expected

    System.out.println("Authority : " + authority);
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(activeUserInfo.getUserName(), activeUserInfo.getPassword(),
            Arrays.asList(authority));
    return userDetails;
}
```

Sysout prints the correct values from DB.

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/server/rest/secure/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "Non Admin").and()  
            .httpBasic().realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());
}
```

**CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint .java**

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

@Override
public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, 
        final HttpServletResponse response, 
        final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName() + "");

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("HTTP Status 401 : " + authException.getMessage());
    response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "FormBased");
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    setRealmName("MY_TEST_REALM");
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

}

But during the login i'm getting `status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access is denied"`

Note: **Earlier I used Base64 for encrypt/decrypt password. But now updated to BCrypt based on this example. So for now testing purpose I have generated BCrypt password online. My pwd is "testing"  BCrypt pwd is "$2a$10$PN/MwjCHtCWsI4auW6Q8AOxb4dug4WSO8tfINySqHZ8eYVjFKIAW6". Did I make any mistake on this?**
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you dont eventually  `.permit()` Please try my code in SecurityConfiguration.java :

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

PS:PUBLIC_MATCHERS is

```
private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
with your folders
    };
```

Comment: Before using `auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());` you need to declare `passwordEncoder` as a bean.